# Detecting parent in table

Tags: jquery, html-table

How to resolve my problem?
I want to click delete and after I click, it delete "delete" button.
My JS Code

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    var parent_1 = $(this).parent();
    var parent_2 = $(parent_1).parent();
    $(parent_2).remove(); 
    });
```

My HTML Code

```
<table>
    <tr id="row_1"> 
        <td>    <input type="submit" class="delete" value="1" />        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please make you question clear, what you trying to do

Comment: I'm sorry. I want to delete tr.

Comment: thanks for all. but my problem is still unfinished

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will remove `<tr>` when you will click any button it will remove related that `<tr>`

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    var parent_1 = $(this).parent().parent();
    $(parent_1).remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to retrieve the parent of `delete` button and also use `.on()` method.Try this:

```
$("table").on('click','.delete',function () {
  var parent_1 = $(this).closest("table");
  $(parent_1).remove(); 
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AFc9W/)

Comment: So the above script is what your looking..Check the demo..it's deleting `<tr>` as you needed..

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.delete').click(function(){
       console.log($('#table').html())
       var parent_1 = $(this).closest("td");
       $(parent_1).remove(); 
       console.log($('#table').html())
   });
```

I guess this what you want

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parents()` to detect your target `TR`. While comparing it with `.Closest()`, It starts `traversing` from the element's `immediate parent`. Not from the `current element`. So that we could minimise one level of `iteration` while using .parents(). For further reading, See here [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

*Additional Notes:* `:first` filter used here because if you have your `button` inside a nested structure, it will be helpful to catch the first one.

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr:first").remove();    
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WpBP2/)